# Paramiko - NoValidConnectionsError - periodically unable to connect to aws instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, paramiko

Infrequently upon creating an instance in aws and then trying to connect I receive the following error from paramiko:

```
NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on 192.168.1.155, fe80::18f3:2388:9bf3:e2d%4 or fe80::49f2:7e18:c58d:aac5%5
```

The code to connect to aws via `ssh_client_for_instance` is:

```
def wait_instance_available(self):
    err_flag = True
    while err_flag:
        print 'waiting for ssh on ',self.instance
        try:
            self.ssh_client = sshclient_from_instance(self.instance,
                                                 'windows-west-keypair.pem',
                                                 user_name='my-ec2-user')

            err_flag = False
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            time.sleep(5)
```

Now, I would assume to code just doesn't work but it does connect to *some* instances I create, just not all.

Anyone have any experience with this?

All instances are created via:

```
new_instances = ec2_res.create_instances(
    ImageId='ami-********',
    MinCount=15,
    MaxCount=50,
    InstanceType='t2.micro',
    KeyName='windows-west-keypair',
    SecurityGroups=[
        'launch-wizard-2']
    )
```

Comment: Yes, I'm observing the same with SageMaker instances actually

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you wait to connect until the instance is "running" this error does not occur.